# angularjs file upload and remove directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

I want to be able to create a simple directive that will be used for loading *and removing* an image file. Can anyone help? 
I would like to be able to specify in html something like 
`<my-image image={{object.image}} newFile={{object.newImage}}> </my-image>`
The directive will show the current, allow replacing it and removing. Result will be in object.newImage. 
Did anyone came across anything similar?

Comment: can you elaborate on your request? I began making a fiddle showing how to properly upload an image: http://jsfiddle.net/TegFf/112/. But I realize now that I re-read your question, I don't know what you mean by "removing an image"? Can you write out point-by-point exactly what the directive would do?

Comment: The directive should translate to a small section, including classes (assume bootstrap), with the following: a. Show current image, a button to remove current image, a button to upload a new image. All will be sent from within a form with additional inputs.

Comment: Okay; so what have you tried? Are you just asking someone to write the directive for you?